# Select entries by day over the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to get the count of the registered users in the past 7 days, grouped.

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| id  | username   | created      |
+-----+------------+--------------+
|  1  | Vlad       | 1360168194   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
|  2  | Test       | 1360168194   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

This is my table. I want to have 7 rows of results with the date of the day, and count(id) as the result for the users that registered.

I tried different solutions and none of them really fitted my needings. Are there any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you're tried

Comment: Yeah, use `datetime` or `date` as datatype for those columns.

Comment: Using a Unix timestamp makes it a PITA to use built in date functions

Comment: As far as I know MYSQL internally uses DATETIME as a unix timestamp, but visibly as a time string. I want to save it `as is´, so whats the best option here? int?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, saving it 'as is'?  Since most of the functions will work on the 'wrapper' type, you're going to lose some time every time you query, because you'll have to convert every value (which means indices are fairly useless).  Use the 'obfucsacted' type - for one thing, it allows the internal representation to be changed, without requiring _you_ to mess with your storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(columName)), COUNT(ID) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
WHERE   DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(columName)) BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL -7 DAY AND CURDATE()
GROUP   BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(columName))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26b50/3)

Other Source(s)

- [MySQL Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: ...`BETWEEN` is _probably_ safe here (given you're only working with dates), but it still makes me twitchy.  Much better to use the explicit range: lower-bound inclusive (`>=`), upper-bound exclusive (`<`), which, if the stored value were timestamps, would be SARGable.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you can't "add" values to dates that way; think it should be `date_add(curdate(), interval -7 day)`